# what is the alternative method "EncodingUtil.base64Encode" in JavaScript or VisualForce?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, contentversion

I have been using EncodingUtil.base64Encode() ; to get base64 contentversion data **aiming to send/upload file from salesforce to outside  server like AWS S3** which was working fine but due to sfdc governor limits  unable to use more than 6MB file.

```
list<ContentVersion> vds = [SELECT Id,VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id=:cvId limit 1];
     b = vds[0].VersionData;
     eb = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(b);
```

So I am re developing alternative approach by JS in visualforce and to get VersionData base64 data I am trying to sf ContentVersion object API `/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/'+cvId+'/VersionData`
which returns special character sets, I guess it is BLOB but BASE64 (as per salesforce manual).

[image]

> How to convert this type of data sets to BASE64?

and with that I have tried to upload file directly to external Server like AWS S3 but it uploaded with corrupted data, so I learned that it might need convert **VersionData** to encoded base64, so for that I have tried to used **btoa()** /
**encodeURIComponent()** in JavaScript Code.
but no luck, the output file seems corrupted.

So I assumed that if I can find alternative Apex method **EncodingUtil.base64Encode()** in JavaScript it might solve it.

My current JS Code snippet..

```
 var url = window.location.origin + '/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/'+cvId+'/VersionData';
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ sessionId);
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {  
                var vblob  = xhr.response;                
**//Here need to Encode/Decode Base64**
                var blobBase64= (( btoa(encodeURIComponent(vblob)) ));
//Convert to Blob
        var fileUrl = "data:" + ContentType + ";base64," + bytesBase64;
        const response = await fetch(fileUrl, {});
        const conBlob = await response.blob();

//conBlob this data is uploading to external API

           }
        };
```

If anyone have similar experience please reply your thought of solution.

-TIA

Comment: you wanna upload file in sf or somewhere else?

Comment: yes already mentioned that to upload file from salesforce to external Server like AWS S3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved by using fetch () with response.blob()..

```
  var fileUrl = window.location.origin + '/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/'+cvId+'/VersionData';
                        
        const response = await fetch(fileUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ sessionId
            }            
        });
        const conBlob = await response.blob();
```

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. However, we do have some rules around here. Instead of saying [RESOLVED], like you might on some forums, simply check the checkbox on the left of your answer to mark it as the best answer.